# How to click a Button in wxWidgets handler OnClose?

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I have a handler for the close button (upper right corner) in a dialog and a handler for an addition button inside the dialog. My custom button has wxID_CANCEL as ID. The handler OnClose should execute the handler OnButtonCancel. What happens: it closes the dialog and the app, because the dialog is in a overwritten wxApp:OnInit. But OnButtonCancel is not executed.

```
void Dialog_Test::OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event) {
    wxCommandEvent event_button_clicked(wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxID_CANCEL);
    event_button_clicked.SetEventObject(this);
    this->ProcessEvent(event_button_clicked);
}

void Dialog_Test::OnButtonCancel(wxCommandEvent& WXUNUSED(event)) {
    wxMessageBox(_("TODO: Dialog_Test::OnButtonCancel")); // <---- not executed
    EndModal(wxID_CANCEL);
}
```

What happens here?

**Edit #1:** In a wxFrame I use ProcessCommand(wxID_CLOSE_FRAME) in OnClose, but in a wxDialog there is no ProcessCommand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the bug:

```
// wrong: don't use ProcessEvent of wxDialog
// this->ProcessEvent(event_button_clicked);

// right: use ProcessEvent of the custom wxButton
GetButtonCancel()->GetEventHandler()->ProcessEvent(event_button_clicked);
```

Comment: That's a really ugly way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a separate function (i.e. `Dialog_Test::DoCancel()`) and call it from both `Dialog_Test::OnClose()` and `Dialog_Test::OnButtonCancel()`.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a cleaner and more flexible code if you approach it as follows:

```
void MyFrame::btnCancelOnClick(wxCommandEvent & event)
{
    wxCommandEvent CloseEvent;
    CloseEvent.SetEventType(wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW);
    CloseEvent.SetEventObject(m_btnCancel);
    wxPostEvent(this, CloseEvent);
}
```

then in OnClose event

```
void MyFrame::OnClose(wxCloseEvent & event)
{
    if (event.GetEventObject() == m_btnOK) {}

    else{
        //Do if cancel button is clicked
    }
    event.Skip();
}
```